# Dictionary replacing values using second dictionary (but searching the value rather than the whole value)

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a value in a dict with another value in a dict. This has been done plenty on here from my searches but I think I have a unique case as I need to search the value for a value rather than replace the whole value.

I have tried this so far and it partially works:

```
input_data = [
    {
        "name": "system1",
        "other_param": "%param1%",
        "secret_text": "%secret%",
        "options": {
            "conditions": "[\"f--updated_at,geq,\\\"%max_date%\\\"\",\"f--status,eq,\\\"Void\\\"\"]"
        }
    }
]

variables = {
    '%secret%': "abc",
    '%param1%': "text_param",
    '%max_date%': '2018-01-01'
}

def process_variables(dict_obj, dict_vars):
    for k, v in dict_obj.items():
        for var, val in dict_vars.items():
            dict_obj[k] = str(v).replace(var, val)

    return dict_obj


for x in input_data:
    print(process_variables(x, variables))
```

The desired result is:

```
{
    "name": "system1",
    "other_param": "text_param",
    "secret_text": "abc",
    "options": {
        "conditions": "[\"f--updated_at,geq,\\\"2018-01-01\\\"\",\"f--status,eq,\\\"Void\\\"\"]"
    }
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
   "name":"system1",
   "other_param":"%param1%",
   "secret_text":"%secret%",
   "options":"{\\'conditions\\': \\'[\"f--updated_at,geq,\\\\\"2018-01-01\\\\\"\",\"f--status,eq,\\\\\"Void\\\\\"\"]\\'}"
}
```

As you can see it seems to flatten the dict down and not replace the top level values.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I can alter the JSON input if needed but I need to do some sort of variable substitution as I have hundreds of inputs with these common values I plan to iterate over.

Comment: You are converting `"conditions": "[\"` into a string (`str(v).replace(var, val)`), that's why the output is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over `input_data` recursively and replace each value separately. Looping recursively has the benefit that you dont need to care how deeply `input_data` is nested:

```
def traverse_dict(dct, replacements):
    if isinstance(dct, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(dct):
            dct[i] = traverse_dict(item, variables)
    elif isinstance(dct, dict):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            dct[k] = traverse_dict(v, variables)
    else:
        # all values in the JSON end up here
        if isinstance(dct, str):
            for repl in replacements:
                if repl in dct:
                    dct = dct.replace(repl, replacements[repl])
        return dct
    return dct

result = traverse_dict(input_data, variables)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "system1", 
        "options": {
            "conditions": "[\"f--updated_at,geq,\\\"2018-01-01\\\"\",\"f--status,eq,\\\"Void\\\"\"]"
        }, 
        "other_param": "text_param", 
        "secret_text": "abc"
    }
]
```

---

Makeing `input_data` more complex, still replaces correctly:

```
input_data = [
    {
        "name": "system1",
        "other_param": "%param1%",
        "secret_text": "%secret%",
        "options": {
            "conditions": "[\"f--updated_at,geq,\\\"%max_date%\\\"\",\"f--status,eq,\\\"Void\\\"\"]",
            "foo": [
                {
                    "bar": {
                        "baz": "%secret%",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "system1", 
        "options": {
            "conditions": "[\"f--updated_at,geq,\\\"2018-01-01\\\"\",\"f--status,eq,\\\"Void\\\"\"]", 
            "foo": [
                {
                    "bar": {
                        "baz": "abc"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "other_param": "text_param", 
        "secret_text": "abc"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Gone with this as it feels a bit safer than the ast suggestion just if keys or anything happened to be named the same as a value.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the result treating the input data as a string and using ast (Abstract Syntax Trees):

```
data = str(input_data)

for k, v in variables.items():
    data = data.replace(k, v)

import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(type(data))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
[{'name': 'system1', 'other_param': 'text_param', 'secret_text': 'abc', 'options': {'conditions': '["f--updated_at,geq,\\"2018-01-01\\"","f--status,eq,\\"Void\\""]'}}]
```

Cant vouch for this being the best way but it simplifies the process. Worth a try?

Comment: Thanks. Gone with the other answer just incase the keys/values match. i wouldnt want to replace them.

Comment: sure .. no problem